# Python: how call a method of another class correctly

Tags: python, class, oop

I have two classes

`check_input_types` - with checking types of input data
`Rules` - getting some data

```
class check_input_types:

    def comparison_operator(op):
        if op == 'совпадает_с':
            return '=='
        elif op == 'не_равно':
            return '!='
        elif op == 'больше':
            return '>'
        elif op == 'меньше':
            return '<'
        else:
            raise Exception('Неверно введен оператор сравнения!')

    def check_input_type(input_type, element):
        if input_type == 'number':
            return int(element)
        elif input_type == 'string':
            return element

class Rules:

    def __init__(self, path):
        with open(path, 'r') as f:
            file = f.read()
        json_parser = Lark(grammar, parser='lalr', postlex=PythonIndenter(), start='if_any')
        if file.endswith('\n'):
            file = file[:-1]
        tree = json_parser.parse(file)

    code = []
    add_indent = ''



    def if_any(t):
        global code

        if t.data == "if_any":
            code.append("if any(")
            for i, child in enumerate(t.children):
                if child.data == "element":
                    comparison_element = check_input_type(child.children[0].data, child.children[0].children[0])
                elif child.data == "comparison":
                    code.append("{} {} x for x in".format(comparison_element, comparison_operator(child.children[0])))
                elif child.data == "array":
                    array = list(check_input_type(element.data, element.children[0][:]) \
                                 for element in child.children)
                    code.append(str(array))
                    code.append('):')
                elif child.data == 'result':
                    code.append("\n\tprint(str({}))".format(child.children[0].children[0]))
```

But there is no calls to method of first class. What is correct way to call it in second class?

Answer (score 0):

First, if you need to work with classes, you should reference it as follows:

```
cit = check_input_types()  # create instance
cit.comparison_operator ('совпадает_с') # call function from instance
```

However, the first variable of a non-static function belonging to a class is not a externally passed variable, but rather a reference to the class itself. Therefore, one usually has *self* as the first parameter (but can be any name).

You can also remove the **comparison_operator** and **check_input_type** functions from the class and then call them the way you are in the Rules class.

P.S.: You need add a self in function of class Rules, to not have error:

```
...
def is_any(self, t):
...
```